# how to extract contents of sharedpreference (string array)

Tags: android

I have this arraylist hashmap

> tasklist = new ArrayList>();

then I store its contents to a preference

```
temp = new HashMap<String, String>();
temp.put("action", spinnerAction.getSelectedItem().toString());
temp.put("task", spinnerCourse.getSelectedItem().toString() + ": " +       spinnerChapter.getSelectedItem().toString());
tasklist.add(temp);
adapterShowTask.notifyDataSetChanged();
editor.putString("taskpref", tasklist.toString());
editor.commit();
```

here is how I retrieve it:

```
String storedCollection = sPrefs.getString("taskpref", "");
```

the contents of storedCollection looks like this:

```
["{action= some text, task= some text}", "{action= some text 2, task= some text 2 }" ]
```

My question is, how do I retrieve the specific string (Action and task) and load it again to the arraylist hashmap?

Comment: IMO, If you want to do that kind of storage, you should use JSON format with GSON.

Comment: can you explain to me how?

Answer (score 0):

That's the JsonString you need to get using jsonparser,I suggested you to learn How to parse      the String json,There is been a lot of great [**`tutorial`**](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) online

```
String storedCollection = sPrefs.getString("taskpref", "");
 JSONArray jarray=new JSONArray(stroredCollection);
 ArrayList<String> action=new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> task=new ArrayList<String>();
 for(i=0;i<jarray.length();i++){
 String action=jarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("action");
 String task=jarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("task");
 }
```